# Insert value to field programmatically and remove cache from field

Tags: 7, entities

I have content type `feature` and i have field `hit_count` in this c.type, also i have `db table - hit_count` - example:

```
nid   hit_count

1     434
2     233
3     512
```

I want to output `hit_count` inside my field - `hit_count` on current node(also should appear on node edit). So for example if node id is `1`, field `hit_count = 434`, and if admin want to edit this field i want to update field value to my table `hit_count` with current `nid` and field value `hit_count`.

To save value into my database table i will use `hook_node_update` and just get fields `nid` and `hit_count` values and update my table.

But i don't know what `hook` should i use or how to insert this value from database to my field. There are lots of nodes with content type `feature`.

**UPDATE**

> **My first thought is - why do you use a separate db table for this rather than simply using an integer field in the content type?**

`Hit count` module was created long time ago, client wanted to disable/enable statistics for every content type, so default `statistics` module does not fit our needs. And now client want to manage this `hit counts` for certain nodes etc...

Also i managed to insert value to edit form on `hook_exit` updated custom hit count module.

```
function hit_count_exit($destination = NULL) {
    if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
        $selected_types = array_filter(variable_get('hit_count_content_types', array()));
        if (!empty($selected_types)) {
            if (in_array($node->type, $selected_types)) {
                db_update('node_hit_counter')
                        ->expression('totalcount', 'totalcount + 1')
                        ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
                        ->execute();
                if($node->type == 'feature') {
                    $val = db_query("SELECT * FROM {node_hit_counter} WHERE nid='$node->nid'")->fetchAll();
                      db_merge('field_data_field_hit_count_node')
                        ->key(array('entity_id' => $node->nid))
                        ->fields(array(
                                'entity_type' => 'node',
                                'bundle' => 'feature',
                                'deleted' => 0,
                                'entity_id' => $node->nid,
                                'revision_id' => $node->nid,
                                'language' => 'und',
                                'delta' => 0,
                                'field_hit_count_node_value' => $val[0]->totalcount,
                        ))
                        ->execute();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But right now i see next problem. I need to get rid of Drupal field cache, cuz i see cached value every time i reload page, and if i clear all caches i get current value of `hit_count`.

Comment: My first thought is - why do you use a separate db table for this rather than simply using an integer field in the content type?

Comment: To update a field on your edit form, you can use hook_form_alter() http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Comment: updated my question, i solved one problem but got another) with `drupal field cache` i need to get rid of it

Answer (score 2):

I also think you could use an integer field on the node for this - but keeping that aside, the  problem you are facing (the inserted value not being refreshed by the cache) is caused by the fact that you are trying to write in the database table `field_data_field_hit_count_node` directly. This is definitely discouraged, and you should be using the proper API instead.

Instead of `db_merge('field_data_field_hit_count_node')->...->execute()` you would want to do something like:

```
$node->field_hit_count_node[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $val[0]->totalcount;
$node->save();
```

Doing it this way ensures that the saving is done by Drupal, the caches are cleared as required, hooks as called as necessary, etc.

In addition if you don't mind using the [entity module](http://drupal.org/project/entity), then you can do this with [Entity Metadata Wrappers](http://drupal.org/node/1021556) in a simpler way:

```
$nw = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$nw->field_hit_count_node = $val[0]->totalcount;
$nw->save();
```

Comment: gonna look at `entity_metadata_wrappers`